# Cannot set application properties via mvn release plugin

Tags: spring-boot, maven, continuous-integration

In CI part most of the times I prefer standard maven phases to execute build steps. In these cases I override application.properties e.g.: -Dlogging.level.root=OFF -Dspring.main.banner-mode=off to turn off debugging logs and save some precious build time.

In some pipelines I prefer to use maven release plugin and I noticed that these flags does not work there.

e.g.: mvn release:prepare -Dspring.main.banner-mode=off

```
[INFO] 
[INFO]   .   ____          _            __ _ _
[INFO]  /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
[INFO] ( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
[INFO]  \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
[INFO]   '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
[INFO]  =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
[INFO]  :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.1.4.RELEASE)
[INFO]
```

Still display spring banner

Any suggestion?

Comment: Of course it won't... The release plugin is for creating a release and update the versions in the pom. It isn't for running or deploying the app.

Comment: I suggest to make an `application.properties` in `src/test/resources` which configures such things cause I assume that those output is generated during an integration test?

Comment: @khmarbaise, correct. 
Dev team expect to have application.properties for dev debugging, thus I should use different profile and then I turn in to the same problem.

mvn -B --batch-mode release:prepare -Dspring.profiles.active=pipeline

Comment: No the default build should always work without any supplemental configuration which makes the release easier and CI easy. If the dev teams needs something special they should make a `application-dev.properties` and activate via spring profile.